# Python not removing element from list

Tags: python, list

I have a dictionary that contains a few questions that I want to ask, with a key that runs from 1 to 7. I also have a list that has the following elements: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, which represents the keys that are used in the dictionary, and I've randomised the list so that the questions are asked at random. However, once the question is asked, I want to remove the first element from the list, so that it can't be asked again, and so that eventually there are no questions left (the actual contents of the element that is to be removed will vary each time), but whenever I run my code, the list remains the same size

```
def random_function():


    questions = {
        1: "Describe what the instruction 'BRP' does.",
        2: "Describe what is meant by the term 'Open Source Software'.",
        3: "What is meant by the term 'Lossy Compression'?",
        4: "What is the number '55' as an 8-bit unsigned integer?",
        5: "What might a printer use RAM for?",
        6: "Describe the term 'firewall'.",
        7: "Describe the Rapid Application Development process."
    }



    random_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    random.shuffle(random_list)

    question = Label(root, bg="white", text=questions[random_list[0]], font = ("Segoe UI", 14))
    question.place(x=20, y=20)

    print(random_list) #just to troubleshoot 

    del(random_list[0])


    root_win2()


def root_win2():
    global question, random_list, questions

    next_button = Button(text="Next Question", command=random_function, height=3, width=12)
    next_button.place(x=370, y=300)
```

(Note that the root_win2() function is run first, and then jumps to the random_function() function after, and that then jumps back to the root_win2() function etc.)

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code snippet is not complete since you refer to things such as `Button` which are not defined in your code. Please edit your code to make it self-contained and complete. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep book of your `random_list` outside the function `random_function` that removes items from it.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Also, everytime the label prints a new question, it places it on top of the previous question, without clearing the previous question. Is this also due to the Label regenerating itself? Should I also place that outside the loop. I did try and do that to see if it would work, by placing it at the very beginning, but it states that the variable "root" (which is the main window), isn't defined. Is there a way to place the "root = Tk()" statement at the very beginning without unnecessarily opening the window open and have the whole program stop working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no looping within the random function so you're creating the list each time, removing the first value, and creating it again.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance it looks like every time you call "random_function()" you are redeclaring random_list to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].

Might want to move random_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] **outside** of the function and make it global as a quick fix so that when you call it again, you are not declaring the same initial array.